# Commands in /usr/bin don't work anymore

Tags: command-line, bash

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Oracle and was following instructions to install Oracle 12c when I accidently deleted the file /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 Now all of the commands from /usr/bin have stopped working. For every command I type, No such file or directory shows up, for eg: if I run

`sudo`

`bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory`

My $PATH variable is fine.

The output of `echo $PATH` is

```
/home/houdini/bin:/home/houdini/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/android-studio/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I don't know what file it was and some suggest complete reinstallation, I'm hoping maybe copying somebody else's /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 running ubuntu 16.04 LTS might solve the problem. Would it? If yes, can someone send me one. Or do i have to reinstall?

Comment: Boot to a live USB of Ubuntu 16.04 and copy that live environment's `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to your installed system.

Comment: @muru Okay, didin't think of that, Thank you. I'll try and let you know. Might take some time though.

Comment: @muru yeah, that wouldn't work because as soon as I plug in a pendrive to create one, `Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/houdini/Kali Live: Error spawning command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/houdini/Kali Live"': Failed to execute child process "mount" (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8)` None of the commands work.

Comment: you'll need to create it with another OS on your system or from another PC.

Comment: @muru Thank you. Did it, everythin's okay now.